# Spring Security OAuth2: multiple ResourceServerConfiguration not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-netflix

Spring boot version: 1.5.8.RELEASE
Spring cloud version: Edgware.RELEASE (using zuul)

Trying to configure multiple resources and, following [this example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/tests/annotation/multi/src/main/java/demo/Application.java) in github, can't make it work.

My code is:

```
class ResourceServerConfigurationFactory
{
    static ResourceServerConfiguration criarResourceServerConfiguration(String resourceId, int order,
            HttpSecurityConfigurer configurer)
    {
        ResourceServerConfiguration resource = new ResourceServerConfiguration()
        {
            // Switch off the Spring Boot @Autowired configurers
            public void setConfigurers(List<ResourceServerConfigurer> configurers)
            {
                super.setConfigurers(configurers);
            }
        };

        resource.setConfigurers(Arrays.<ResourceServerConfigurer>asList(new ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception
            {
                resources.resourceId(resourceId);
            }

            @Override
            public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
            {
                configurer.configure(http);
            }
        }));

        resource.setOrder(order);

        return resource;
    }
}

interface HttpSecurityConfigurer
{
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception;
}
```

And my configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuthResourceConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    protected ResourceServerConfiguration usuarioResources()
    {
        return ResourceServerConfigurationFactory.criarResourceServerConfiguration("usuario", -10,
                http -> http.antMatcher("/user").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll());
    }

    @Bean
    protected ResourceServerConfiguration funcaoResources()
    {
        return ResourceServerConfigurationFactory.criarResourceServerConfiguration("funcao", -20,
                http -> http.antMatcher("/ws").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll());
    }   
}
```

Finally, the Spring boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableZuulProxy
public class ApiGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Facts:

- Spring instantiates both ResourceServerConfiguration beans;
- Only the bean with higher order works (/user endpoint is ok, /ws endpoint keeps asking authentication)
- In spring log, I can see that only /user ant matcher is used. /ws gets completely ignored.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the Factory class I created.

The combination of lambda + anonymous class created some kind of problem (that I was not able to understand) that screwed up things.

Declaring both Configurers as Beans in the @Configuration class resolved the problem.